# Android Deep Link не отрабатывает при первом запуске

Tags: android, firebase, deeplink

У нас в приложении настроены и работают Firebase диплинки, которые работаю по следующему алгоритму:
 - Если на устройстве есть приложение, то будет запущено приложение и система получит url в интенте
 - Если на устройстве нет приложения, то будет запущен плей-маркет и после установки будет запущено приложение и система получит url в интенте.

Всё работает замечательно за исключением того, что при первом запуске у нового пользователя данные не приходят - intent пустой.

Если хотя бы раз установить или запустить приложение и затем кликнуть на диплинку - всё работает. Даже после удаления и новой установки приложения.

Но если сбросить телефон в заводские настройки, создать новый аккаунт в гугле и запустить диплинку - данных нет. При втором и последующих запусках есть.

**Коллеги, сталкивался ли кто-нибудь из вас с указанной проблемой и как вы её решали?**

Additional info:

- версия плей-маркета и гугл-сервисов не имеет значения - репродьюс 100%
- телефоны использовались разные, в основном 6 и 7 Андроид - репродьюс 100%
- Заполнен и работает файл верфикации [https://хост/.well-known/assetlinks.json](https://%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82/.well-known/assetlinks.json) где перечислены все хосты из манифеста
- Диплинка имеет следующий вид [https://хост.app.goo.gl/?link=https://хост/api/tickets/?represent_action%3service%26auth_key%3DmYtrTtF9j%26auth_token%3DyIkLhX_AxeoAkMRKuzJHK97s&apn=com.example](https://%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82.app.goo.gl/?link=https://%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82/api/tickets/?represent_action%253service%26auth_key%3DmYtrTtF9j%26auth_token%3DyIkLhX_AxeoAkMRKuzJHK97s&apn=com.example)
- Если включить режим дебага для диплинки, то видим, что она трансформируется в ссылку для плеймаркета https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.example&pcampaignid=fdls_long&url=https://%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82/api/tickets/?represent_action%253service%26auth_key%3DmYtrTtF9j%26auth_token%3DyIkLhX_AxeoAkMRKuzJHK97s&apn=com.example, но при первом запуске то, что находится после url= не приходит

Хелп)

Comment: Составили письмо в фаербейс, ведём переписку. По результатам доложу )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С фаербейса прислали ответ на письмо, что это ошибка. Так что вопрос ответа не имеет, мы всё делали правильно.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]